Problem with query in Azure Resource Graph Explorer
I'm very new to KQL.
I'm trying to find which resources are using a storage account with this query:
resources
| where type == "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts"
| project StorageAccountName = name, ResourceId = id
| join kind=inner (
    resourcecontainers
    | project ResourceId, ResourceName, ResourceType
) on $left.ResourceId == $right.ResourceId
| project StorageAccountName, ResourceGroup

Error
ResourceId, ResourceName, ResourceType, and ResourceGroup does not refer to any known column, table, variable or function.

I can't find any tables with these names, so that makes sense. Are there any similar tables? Or am i doing this completely wrong?
Expect to see which resources in Azure that use a particular storage account


I'm trying to find which resources are using a storage account with this query.

AFAIK, it is not possible in to fetch which resources are using a storage account with KQL query.
You can use the below PowerShell script to fetch the resources using a storage account by diagnostic settings.
Script:
Connect-AzAccount

Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId 'xxxxxx'

Write-Output "`r`n"

# Get all resources in the subscription
$resources = Get-AzResource
 
# Loop through each resource and check if it has Azure monitor with storage diagnostic enabled
foreach ($resource in $resources) {
    $resourceName = $resource.Name
    $resourceType = $resource.ResourceType
    $resourceId = $resource.ResourceId

 
    # Check if the resource has Azure monitor with storage diagnostic enabled
    $diagnosticSettings = Get-AzDiagnosticSetting -ResourceId $resourceId -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($diagnosticSettings -ne $null -and $diagnosticSettings.StorageAccountId -ne $null) {
        $storageAccountId = $diagnosticSettings.StorageAccountId
        Write-Output "$resourceId of Type ($resourceType) has Azure monitor with storage diagnostic enabled. Storage account ID: $storageAccountId"
        
    }
}

Output:
/subscriptions/xxxxx9-a971-e7c0e43fec67/resourceGroups/venkatesan-rg/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/venkat326123 of Type (Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts) has Azure monitor 
with storage diagnostic enabled. Storage account ID: /subscriptions/b82xxxxx971-e7c0e43fec67/resourcegroups/venkatesan-rg/providers/microsoft.storage/storageaccounts/venkat8912


Reference:
Azure-CXP-Developer-Support/Storage/Blob/Powershell/ListAzureResourceUsingStorageAccount at main · Azure-Samples/Azure-CXP-Developer-Support (github.com)

Thank you so much! Will try this out tomorrow
